# Populate a string multidimensional or jagged array in a c# class parameter

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm pretty much new to c# and I'm having trouble populating a multidimensional or jagged array (I'm not even sure which one I need tbh).

**This is the code I have so far**

```
class CustomFields
{
    public Array vehicle_options { get; set; }
}

var custom_fields = new CustomFields();
// options_list is populated from an external web service
List<Options> options_list = new List<Options>(); 
List<string> options = new List<string>();

foreach (Option option in options_list)
{
    options.Add(option.name.Value); //Option name is a string
}
    custom_fields.vehicle_options = options.ToArray();
```

With this code I'm getting an array that looks like this:

```
["vehicle_options"] => 
    [0] => "Some value",
    [1] => "Some other value",
    ...
```

**This is what I'm trying to achieve**

```
["vehicle_options"] => 
    [0] => 
        ["vehicle_option"] => "Some value",
    [1] =>
        ["vehicle_option"] => "Some other value",
    ...
```

So basically I'm trying to set a key for all option name values. And it will always be "vehicle_option".

I'm pretty sure I need to declare my array differently and add the values differently than what I tried so far... I tried many different approaches, but just can't seem to get it working...

**EDIT**

`options_list` is a list of "vehicle option objects" that I'm getting from an external source. These "option objects" have a name property which I am extracting and using them to populate the array.

Any tips on how I can achieve this (using as much of the existing code as possible)?

**EDIT2**

This is my "fix" attempt for @Snapshot's answer:

```
class CustomFields
{ 
public Dictionary<string, string>[] vehicle_options { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<string, string>[] vehicleOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>[]()
{
    new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"vehicle_option", "Value1"},
    },
    new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"vehicle_option", "Value2"},
    },
    new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"vehicle_option", "Value3"},
    }
};
custom_fields.vehicle_options = vehicleOptions;
```

Comment: what is `options_list` ?

Comment: Is a list of options what you need?

Comment: @zackraiyan check my edit please.

Comment: your code still doesn't contain `options_list` , what is it ?? and what is ur goal/expected result ?

Comment: @zackraiyan I'm not sure that options_list is relevant, it's basically just a list of strings (or more correctly a list of objects with a string parameter).  My expected result is to get a final array that looks like the one I mentioned in the "This is what I'm trying to achieve" section. Basically all I need is to insert the "vehicle_option" key (which is a fixed string) as the key for all extracted vehicle option name values.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying the rational **why** you would like to use a nested array with the fixed string `vehicle_option`? When the text is always the same it could very likely be ommited? Especially because it seems to be the same as the parent element. It just seems to me that there is room for improvement of the overall concept.

Comment: @Snapshot The fixed string vehicle_option is needed because it is neccesary for a REST api call. The sent object needs to be in the format [vehicle_options][0][vehicle_option] => option value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use your array in a way that would seem reasonable for a `Dictionary<string, string>` or a `Dictionary<string, object>`.

```
class CustomFields
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> VehicleOptions { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}

var custom_fields = new CustomFields();
foreach (Option option in options_list)
{
    custom_fields.VehicleOptions.Add(option.name.Value, "default value"); //Option name is a string
}
```

you could then access a specific option by using its name

```
var height = custom_fields.VehicleOptions["Height"];
```

or iterate over the whole dictionary in case you do not know the possible options before hand.

```
foreach (var optionsKeyValue in custom_fields.VehicleOptions)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {optionsKeyValue.Key} Value: {optionsKeyValue.Value}");
}
```

**Edit**

Would you mind testing if the following would return the correct result?

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>[]> vehicleOptions = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>[]>()
{
    {"vehicle_options", new Dictionary<string, string>[]
        {
            new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"vehicle_options", "Value1"},
            },
            new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"vehicle_options", "Value2"},
            },
            new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"vehicle_options", "Value3"},
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Edit 2**
Assuming the structure is dependant on your already existing class `CustomFields`.

```
class CustomFields
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> vehicle_options { get; set; } = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

    public void AddVehicleOption(string value)
    {
        var options = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        options.Add("vehicle_options", value);
        vehicle_options.Add(options);
    }
}

var custom_fields = new CustomFields();
foreach (Option option in options_list)
{
    custom_fields.AddVehicleOption(option.name.Value); //Option name is a string
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but seems that the "key" is set as the "value", while the "value" is set to "default value" with your code. What I really need is to have the key fixed as "vehicle_option" and the "value" to be dynamic based on options_list. I tried to switch positions of `option.name.Value` and `default value`, but seems that a duplicate key exception occurs. Thank you for the effort though... If you have any other idea, would be appreciated!

Comment: I tried it and it seems close, but still not fully correct unfortunately. The problem seems to be that the "vehicle_options" key isn't necessary because the original class "custom_fields" contains a parameter "vehicle_options" which I am filling with [0][vehicle_option][value1], [1][vehicle_option][value2]. So it seems that you went "a step too far". I tried adjusting it, but got syntax errors (I'm new to c#...). I'll post the latest code in a question edit, maybe you can spot the error?

Comment: Works great! Thanks a million!